# Trying to install postgres for Ruby on linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems

im trying to install PG for a project and keep getting the following error while running bundle install:

An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

If i try to run `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`, it freezes my console, any ideas of a fix?

Comment: Have you tried just `install pg -v '0.18.4'`

Comment: What do you get when you run `gem sources`

Comment: Hi, 

When I try that it then says this"install pg -v '0.18.4'" cannot stat 'pg': No such file or directory

When I run gem sources it says:
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
root@ubuntu:~/mycollect#

Comment: Do you have postgresql installed on your linux machine?

Comment: Also the stack trace above the message would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Xmfd1yf9

Comment: So you are 100% sure you can log in to postgres with this: sudo -u postgres psql

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, how I fixed it was I ran

apt-get install libpq-dev

then

sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4'

then tried to bundle install and was successful